# Program authorisations under windows - Security tab

Tags: windows, security, server, administrator

I'm having trouble with several of my programs, using Windows server 2012 R2.
As they seem to be deemed Dangerous by Windows, the administrator group is constantly removed as an owner in the properties => Security tab.

It is the only owner of the program as it is the only group on my server (the screen shows differently as it is on a different computer).

http://prntscr.com/bjxkgy (this screen is Under Windows 10, but is essentially the same).

When I add the administrator group back, my program functions perfectly for a few seconds, before being closed, and getting removed for the admin group again.
There is no antivirus software.

As I have no access to my server at the moment I cannot show you the error that pops when I try to launch the program without any groups.

This is stopping me from working a lot, and I've had this problem for the past few weeks, but I have found no relevant answer on the internet, as every research leads me to standard Windows related security questions.

My real question would be : Why is the administrator group getting removed from the security tab on its own, and how to stop that from happening ?

Thank you very much.